# Is it normal to tests not be able to create queues because there's one with the same name on the organization?

Tags: apex, failing-tests, queue

If I have, for example, in production a `MyQueue` queue, with the same DeveloperName, and I'm trying to run a test class to deploy a change set, which contains a test that inserts a `MyQueue` queue as well, is it normal that the test fails with a `DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME` error? The test does **not** have the `@seeAllData` annotation.

Also, there's another method which queries the queues, and it is being able to see the queues on the environment, outside the tests. It was supposed to read just the queue that was created during the test though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup Objects, like Queues and Users, can be queried without SeeAllData in unit tests. There's no need to explicitly create these objects under normal circumstances. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm) says:

> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create. However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> - User
> - Profile
> - Organization
> - AsyncApexJob
> - CronTrigger
> - RecordType
> - ApexClass
> - ApexTrigger
> - ApexComponent
> - ApexPage

Note that this list is not exhaustive; other types of setup objects are also available.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this? Or it would be best practice to adapt the tests to read those setup objects from the environment?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Assuming your code *depends* on the queue for proper operation, I would read it from the environment. If you forget to migrate the queue, your test should fail, alerting you to the fact that you forgot to migrate the queue. Consider it a safety mechanism.